# Why layer 7 load balancer cannot pass through SSL termination?

Tags: ssl, load-balancing

I need to share ssl termination task among server farm or multiple processes. In this architecture, there should be a load balancer before this ssl termination task. After looking for an appropriate software load balancer a while, it turn out that only layer 4 (TCP) load balancers (haproxy) are suitable for this job rather than layer 7 (HTTP/HTTPS) ones.

My question is, why layer 7 load balancers like nginx, perlbal cannot just pass through ssl termination? Client IP addresses should be available in layer 7 load balancer. They can just forward requests, right?

The architecture is like:

```
HTTPS balancer (L4/TCP balancer)
  / | \        <--- HTTPS traffic
SSL server farm/processes
  \ | /        <--- HTTP traffic
HTTP balancer (L7/HTTP balancer)
  / | \
HTTP server farm/processes
```

Reference: http://1wt.eu/articles/2006_lb/index_09.html

Comment: HAProxy 1.5 can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP layer just route traffic with added headers/control over network packets from the underlying layer. It has no knowledge of what it transports, thus does not need to deal with its content, and whether it is HTTP(S). **HTTP/HTTPS does not matter**.

When dealing with the application layer, you are deep down within content, since you deal with an application. In case of HTTPS, you will need SSL termination. **HTTP/HTTPS does matter**.

Thus, if you want to load-balance at application level, you will then need to do SSL termination on the same load-balancers. nginx allows you to do that.

If you wish to separate those tasks, you will need a network/routing-level load-balancer.